# Vincular string inserida em um campo 'sub-categoria' a uma categoria

Tags: php, mysql

Boa noite.
Tenho um input 'categoria', onde o usuário seleciona as categorias existentes, e abaixo um campo 'subcategoria', caso o usuário deseje cadastrar.
No Mysql já tem as tabelas criadas, são elas: tbdcategoria (idCategoria, dscCategoria), e tbdsubcategoria (idSubcategoria, dscSubcategoria, idCategoria).

Como posso fazer para quando o usuário clicar em 'cadastrar', vincular a subcategoria criada a categoria selecionada?

Comment: vc ja esta relacionando as duas tabelas

Answer (score 0):

Caso seja como fazer isto com o php. Simplesmente pegue o dados do input da categoria com Get ou Post e insira no banco de dados usando uma query pelo PDO ou através dos metodos da usa ORM se estiver utilizando.

Caso seja como fazer isto no banco de dados, você precisa criar uma CHAVE ESTRANGEIRA (FK - Foreign Key) da categoria na tabela subcategoria assim você vai ter um campo na tabela tbdsubcategoria com o idCategoria que estara referenciando a ID da categoria cadastrada na tabela de categorias. Você vai simplesmente pegar a id da categoria e adicionar no cadastro da tabela subcategoria

Isto é o basico de banco de dados relacionais. Sugiro que estude sobre o assunto para mais informações

Documentação do MySql para criar chave estrangeira: [Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)